# jquery .submit live click runs more than once

Tags: ajax, post, submit, jquery

I use the following code to run my form ajax requests but when i use the live selector on a button i can see the ajax response fire 1 time, then if i re-try it 2 times, 3 times, 4 times and so on...

I use `.live` because i also have a feature to add a post and that appears instantly so the user can remove it without refreshing the page...

Then this leads to the above problem... using `.click` could solve this but it's not the ideal solution i'm looking for...

```
jQuery.fn.postAjax = function(success_callback, show_confirm) {
    this.submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (show_confirm == true) {
            if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item? You can\'t undo this.')) {
                $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), $.proxy(success_callback, this));
            }
        } else {
            $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), $.proxy(success_callback, this));
        }
        return false;
    })
    return this;
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".delete_button").live('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().postAjax(function(data) {
            if (data.error == true) {

            } else {

            }
        }, true);
    });
});​
```

**EDIT: temporary solution is to change**

```
this.submit(function(e) {
```

to

```
this.unbind('submit').bind('submit',function(e) {
```

the problem is how can i protect it for real because people who know how to use Firebug or the same tool on other browsers can easily alter my Javascript code and re-create the problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't want a new click event bound every time you click the button you need to unbind the event before re-binding it or you end up with multiple bindings.

To unbind events bound with `live()` you can use `die()`. I think the syntax using `die()` with `live()` is similar to this (*untested*):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.delete_button').die('click').live('click', function(){
        $(this).parent().postAjax(function(data){
            if (data.error == true){
            }else{
            }
        }, true);
    });
});
```

However, if you are using jQuery 1.7 or later use `on()` instead of `live()` as `live()` has been deprecated since 1.7 and has many drawbacks.
See [**documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/live/) for all the details.

To use `on()` you can bind like this (I'm assuming the `delete_button` is a dynamically added element) :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).off('click', '.delete_button').on('click', '.delete_button', function(){
        $(this).parent().postAjax(function(data){
            if (data.error == true){
            }else{
            }
        }, true);
    });
});
```

If you are using an earlier version of jQuery you can use `undelegate()` or `unbind()` and `delegate()` instead. I believe the syntax would be similar to `on()` above.

**Edit (29-Aug-2012)**

> the problem is how can i protect it for real because people who know
>   how to use Firebug or the same tool on other browsers can easily alter
>   my Javascript code and re-create the problem

You can some-what protect your scripts but you cannot prevent anyone from executing their own custom scripts against your site.

To at least protect your own scripts to some degree you can:

- Write any script in an external js file and include a reference to that in your site
- Minify your files for release

#### Write any script in an external js file and include a reference to that in your site

That will make your html clean and leave no trace of the scripts. A user can off course see the script reference and follow that for that you can minify the files for release.

To include a reference to a script file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/myscript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/myscript.min.js"></script>
```

#### Minify your files for release

Minifying your script files will remove any redundant spacing and shorten function names to letters and so no. Similar to the minified version of JQuery. The code still works but it is meaningless. Off course, the hard-core user could follow meaningless named code and eventually figure out what you are doing. However, unless you are worth hacking into I doubt anyone would bother on the average site.

Personally I have not gone through the minification process but here are some resources:

- [**Wikipedia - Minification (programming)**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29)
- [**Combine, minify and compress JavaScript files to load ASP.NET pages faster**](http://atashbahar.com/post/Combine-minify-compress-JavaScript-files-to-load-ASPNET-pages-faster.aspx)
- [**How to minify (not obfuscate) your JavaScript using PHP**](http://bytes.com/topic/php/insights/796602-how-minify-not-obfuscate-your-javascript-using-php)

**Edit (01-Sep-2012)**

In response to `adeneo`'s comment regarding the use of [**one()**](http://api.jquery.com/one/). 
I know you already found a solution to your problem by unbinding and rebinding to the submit event.

I believe though it is worth to include a mentioning of `one()` in this answer for completeness as binding an event with [**one()**](http://api.jquery.com/one/) only executes the event ones and then unbinds itself again.

As your click event, when triggered, re-loads and rebinds itself anyway `one()` as an alternative to unbinding and re-binding would make sense too.

The syntax for that would be similar to `on()`, keeping the dynamic element in mind.

```
// Syntax should be right but not tested.
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).one('click', '.delete_button', function() {
        $(this).parent().postAjax(function(data) {
            if (data.error == true) {} else {}
        }, true);
    });
});​
```

#### Related Resources

- [**live()**](http://api.jquery.com/live/)
- [**die()**](http://api.jquery.com/die/)
- [**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
- [**off()**](http://api.jquery.com/off/)
- [**unbind()**](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)
- [**delegate()**](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)
- [**undelegate()**](http://api.jquery.com/undelegate/)
- [**one()**](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

---

**EDIT AGAIN !!!! :**

```
jQuery.fn.postAjax = function(show_confirm, success_callback) {
    this.off('submit').on('submit', function(e) { //this is the problem, binding the submit function multiple times
        e.preventDefault();
        if (show_confirm) {
            if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item? You can\'t undo this.')) {
                $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), $.proxy(success_callback, this));
            }
        } else {
            $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), $.proxy(success_callback, this));
        }
    });
    return this;
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(this).on('click', '.delete_button', function(e) {
        $(e.target.form).postAjax(true, function(data) {
            if (data.error) {

            } else {

            }
        });
    });
});​
```

Comment: I tried both ways but still i get the confirm_box() multiple times as i click the delete button and the request was not completed... such as if i get an error on the first time... and then re-try the request will hit 2 times, then 3 times etc...

Comment: @fxuser: If you are using jQuery below 1.8 you can try using `console.log($('.delete_button').data('events'))`, that will output to the console all the events attached to the element. In the chrome console you can then easily expand the click event array object to see if the number of events attached, just to confirm it is the same vent bound many times. `data('events')` will not show any in-line event bindings though, i.e: `<button onClick='myFunction'...`. In general the issue you are describing sounds very much like events are not being unbound before re-bound.

Comment: i have got a temporary solution but if someone alter the javascript code then they can re-create the problem and post multiple times to the server - check edited question

Comment: Not sure if it's right, but it's just so detailed that you can't not +1 it ?

Comment: @adeneo: Thanks for the feedback. I tried listing the reason I could think of which cause duplicate event binding and how to prevent it. Regarding the minification to protect against custom script I'm not sure if this is the right way but minification does make it harder to see what's going on. If there is any information which is incorrect please let me know. It is important for anyone coming across this in the future to get good information.

Comment: The problem is mainly that the event is bound inside a function that is being called on every click (big no-no), so it's bound over and over, and the effect would be exactly what the OP describes, no matter how the event is bound (click, on, live etc). The easy solution would be to just bind it once with `one()` on every instatiation, which also supports delegation just like `on()`. As for protecting JS from savvy users, it can't be done. Period!

Comment: @adeneo: I thought about `one()` but then assumed that unbinding it before binding in this instance it would solve it as well. I will add `one()` to the answer if you don't mind as that is good information.

Comment: Actually, looking closer at the code, I don't really see why it would bind the event severaly times, and there seems to be something weird about the way callbacks are handled, and the way it returns false, or returns anything really, as it is'nt chained. There's just some hinky parts in that postAjax plugin, but I don't have the time to test it ?

Comment: @adeneo: I added `one()` as another alternative to the unbind/rebind suggestions. Even if it does not solve the issue as such due to other possible unknown influences from the plug-in you mentioned I feel it should be included for completeness sake. Thanks again for your feedback.

Comment: Actually, the problem is in the second line of the plugin, edited your answer to show what seems to be a working code, all though rewriting the plugin as to not bind the submit function in that way would be better. I changed a few other things as well, and I'm pretty sure the proxy functions are'nt really needed, and seem like a strange addition, but as I'm not sure why they are used, I kept them.

Comment: @adeneo: Ah, I see. If I understood you right it was the submit event which was bound multiple times. In that case it does make sense why the click event of the button was too, regardless of what we tried on the button directly. Nicely done.

Comment: guys thanks for the help here.. really appreciate it... but since the edit of the question i got it working but my main problem is how to secure it from other hackers that try to remove the fix and then they will be able to post multiple times on one click... as i said without the fix when i submit a form it gets submitted 1,2,3,4 times each time

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.fn.postAjax = function(success_callback, show_confirm) {
    this.bind( 'submit.confirmCallback', //give your function a namespace to avoid removing other callbacks
      function(e) {
        $(this).unbind('submit.confirmCallback');
        e.preventDefault();
        if (show_confirm === true) {
            if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item? You can\'t undo this.')) {
                $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), $.proxy(success_callback, this));
            }
        } else {
            $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), $.proxy(success_callback, this));
        }
        return false;
    })
    return this;
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".delete_button").live('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().postAjax(function(data) {
            if (data.error == true) {

            } else {

            }
        }, true);
    });
});​
```

As for the "people could use Firebug to alter my javascript" argument, it does not hold : people can also see the request that is sent by your `$.post(...)`, and send it twice.

You do not have control over what happens in the browser, and should protect your server side treatment, rather than hoping that "it won't show twice in the browser, so it will prevent my database from being corrupt".